# Admin import - Group not found

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I am trying to load multiple csv files into a new db using the neo4j-admin import tool on a machine running Debian 11. To try to ensure there's no collisions in the ID fields, I've given every one of my node and relationship files.
However, I'm getting this error:

```
org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.input.HeaderException: Group 'INVS' not found. Available groups are: [CUST]
```

This is super frustrating, as I *know* that the INV group definitely exists. I've checked every file that uses that ID Space and they all include it.
Another strange thing is that there are more ID spaces than just the CUST and INV ones. It feels like it's trying to load in relationships before it finishes loading in all of the nodes for some reason.
Here is what I'm seeing when I search through my input files

```
$ grep -r -h "(INV" ./import | sort | uniq
:ID(INVS),total,:LABEL
:START_ID(INVS),:END_ID(CUST),:TYPE
:START_ID(INVS),:END_ID(ITEM),:TYPE
```

The top one is from my `$NEO4J_HOME/import/nodes` folder, the other two are in my `$NEO4J_HOME/import/relationships` folder.

Is there a nice solution to this? Or have I just stumbled upon a bug here?

Edit: here's the command I've been using from within my $NEO4J_HOME directory: 
`neo4j-admin import --force=true --high-io=true --skip-duplicate-nodes --nodes=import/nodes/\.* --relationships=import/relationships/\.*`

Comment: how about posting the commands you used?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Oh jeez I forgot to post that, whoops. I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, such a thing would be great, but i don't think it's possible at the moment.

Anyway it doesn't seems a bug.
I suppose it may be a wanted behavior and / or a feature not yet foreseen.

In fact, [on the documentation regarding the regular expression](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/neo4j-admin-import/#import-tool-syntax) it says:

```
Assume that you want to include a header and then multiple files that matches a pattern, e.g. containing numbers. 
In this case a regular expression can be used
```

while on the description of `--nodes` command:

```
Node CSV header and data. Multiple files will be
                               logically seen as one big file from the
                               perspective of the importer. The first line must
                               contain the header. Multiple data sources like
                               these can be specified in one import, where each
                               data source has its own header.
```

So, it appears that the `neo4j-admin import` considers the `--nodes=import/nodes/\.*` as a single `.csv` with the first header found, hence the error.
Contrariwise with more `--nodes` there are no problems.

Comment: This did it! I just had to add a `--nodes=` for each individual node type, then the same for relationships and it worked! Thank you so much!!!